# Clojure : define 2D-primitives arrays like double[][]

Tags: arrays, clojure

I have a 2D vector like

```
(def data [[1 1] [1 1]])
```

I would like to turn it into double[][].

i examined clojure.core and I tried :

1)

```
(->> (map double-array data)
     (to-array-2d))
```

Unfortnately it returns Object[][] type of data, which fails in Java interop.

2)

```
(->> (map double-array data)
     (double-array))
```

Of course it does not work because double-array expects a collection of numbers

3) I did not code it since it's heavy and I do not know if something esle exist but I could initialize a double[][] with (make-array Double/Type 2 2) [2 2 got by alen] and then fill it with loops.
Like in Java in fact.

4) A short way but a bit twisted

```
(def double-2d-array-type
  (type (double-array [])))

  (->> (map double-array data)
       (into-array double-2d-array-type)))
```

Is there a direct way ? If it was possible to call directly double[] it would be better.

Like "(into-array double[] data)"

Comment: does `(into-array (Class/forName "[D") (map double-array [[1.0 1.2] [1.3 1.5]]))` => `#object["[[D" 0x16eccb2e "[[D@16eccb2e"]` address this?

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868192/how-do-i-create-a-primitive-two-dimensional-2d-array-of-doubles-in-clojure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the first argument to `into-array`:

```
(into-array (map double-array data))
```

As long as there is at least one element in the input sequence, `into-array` can look at its type to guess the desired type of the output array. This guess isn't always what you want, because of inheritance, but for primitives it will never be wrong.