# Clojure create two-dimensional array with default value

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, clojure

How I can create two-dimensional array (matrix) with some default value in Clojure?

Example:

```
user=> (double-array-2d 3 4 Double/MIN_VALUE)
[[4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324],
 [4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324],
 [4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324]]
```

And how I can mutate this later?

```
user=> (def arr2d (double-array-2d 3 4 0))
user=> (set! arr2d 1 1 5)
user=> (pprint arr2d)
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
nil
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking....?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a primitive two-dimensional (2d) array of doubles in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868192/how-do-i-create-a-primitive-two-dimensional-2d-array-of-doubles-in-clojure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to initialize with a default value or any other sequence input, you can feed typed arrays into `into-array`:

```
(def arr2d
  (into-array (repeat 3 (double-array 4 Double/MIN_VALUE))))
```

`double-array` and other typed array constructors can take either a default value or an input sequence.

```
(clojure.pprint/pprint arr2d)
[[4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324],
 [4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324],
 [4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324]]
```

There's also a `make-array` function, you just give it a type and dimension(s), but it doesn't take a default value:

```
(make-array Double/TYPE 3 2)
=> #object["[[D" 0x3ae2ca60 "[[D@3ae2ca60"]
(def arr2d (make-array Double/TYPE 3 4))
```

You can use `aset` to set a value at given indices:

```
(aset arr2d 1 1 5)
=> 5
```

This has mutated the array in-place, and printing `arr2d` reflects that:

```
(clojure.pprint/pprint arr2d)
;; [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

For creating two-dimensional array in Clojure, You can refer predefined Function **"*to-array-2d*"** from [here](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/to-array-2d).

Answer (score 0):

here's an example using `java.util.Arrays/fill to fill each array

```
user> (defn my-array [x y]
        (let [arr (make-array Double/TYPE x y)]
          (doseq [i (range x)]
                 (java.util.Arrays/fill (aget arr i) Double/MIN_VALUE))
          arr))
#'user/my-array

user> (def thing (my-array 3 4))
#'user/thing

user> (doseq [i (range 3)
              j (range 4)]
        (println (aget thing i j)))
4.9E-324
4.9E-324
4.9E-324
4.9E-324
4.9E-324
4.9E-324
4.9E-324
4.9E-324
4.9E-324
4.9E-324
4.9E-324
4.9E-324
```