# Passing a 2D array of Integers into Java from Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

In my Java library I have a function

```
void f(Integer[][] grid) {
```

and I want to call it from Clojure

```
(f (to-array-2d
       [[1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1]
       [0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0]]) )
```

The problem is, that the Clojure seems to be putting the data into generic Object class. While my functions wants Integers

Error message :

> actual: java.lang.ClassCastException: class [[Ljava.lang.Object;
>   cannot be cast to class [[Ljava.lang.Integer; ([[Ljava.lang.Object;
>   and [[Ljava.lang.Integer; are in module java.base of loader
>   'bootstrap')

How can I tell Clojure to put these into Integers? Or do I have to write my Java using Object?

Comment: untested: `(into-array ^"[[Ljava.lang.Integer" (map int-array [[1 0] [0 1]]))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868192/how-do-i-create-a-primitive-two-dimensional-2d-array-of-doubles-in-clojure/3868611

Comment: Yep, that works

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```clj
(defn into-2d-array
  [cast-fn matrix]
  (into-array
    (map (fn [array]
           (into-array (map cast-fn array)))
         matrix)))
(into-2d-array  double [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]])
;; => #object["[[Ljava.lang.Double;" 0xf49bc94 "[[Ljava.lang.Double;@f49bc94"]

(into-2d-array  int [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]])
;; => #object["[[Ljava.lang.Integer;" 0x2bf30c58 "[[Ljava.lang.Integer;@2bf30c58"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never had a chance to try this.  Made some demo code to show it in action:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (let [i0 (into-array Short/TYPE (range 3))]
    (newline)
    (spyx i0)
    (spyxx (first i0)))
  (let [i1 (short-array (range 3))]
    (newline)
    (spyx i1)
    (spyxx (first i1)))
  (let [data (mapv short-array [[1 2 3] [4 5]])
        i2 (into-array  data)]
    (newline)
    (spyx i2)
    (spyx (first i2))
    (spyxx (first (first i2))))
  )
```

with results:

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 13
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

i0 => #object["[S" 0x3d945944 "[S@3d945944"]
(first i0) => <#java.lang.Short 0>

i1 => #object["[S" 0x6ae6df4a "[S@6ae6df4a"]
(first i1) => <#java.lang.Short 0>

i2 => #object["[[S" 0xf610578 "[[S@f610578"]
(first i2) => #object["[S" 0x4b0e6ed6 "[S@4b0e6ed6"]
(first (first i2)) => <#java.lang.Short 1>
```